# Java cardSending data recieved 6f 00 error code

Tags: android, javacard, elliptic-curve, apdu

I have created ECC (Elliptic curve cryptography) in jcop j3A081 card.(dual interface card).Then i have android Application which use the Android ISO dep Connection to Communicate with the java card.(Contactless interface).So First i have select the Application.It gives success response code(90 00).So then i send some data to card it gives encryption data back to Android Application.Previously it worked perfectly.but suddenly it corrupted. I don't know why.After Corrupted it successfully selected Application but when i try to send data to java card it gives (6F 00) error code.previously it gives the encrypted data.Is there Any one knows what is happening in java card ?? or what is the root course??(Spec : I used this card many time for the testing)

Thanks
Sajith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will have to debug your Applet. The issue is that `6F00` is returned when any exception is thrown by the `process` method other than `ISOException`.

This could for instance include issues regarding memory management. Once in the field, you should not allocate new objects or request transient memory arrays. Note that JavaCard has not much of a garbage collector, even if it is present.

It may also be the case that you've worn out the flash or EEPROM memory somehow. For that to happen you have to write many times to the same location or block though.

Comment: Thanks owlstead. This is the real problem.Previously i didn't have used transient arrays.So Thanks your help

Comment: If you are expecting problems or if you want to debug your Applet, then add a try/catch as close to the problem location and rethrow an ISOException, e.g. with information from the previous reason code and the exception type.

Comment: thanks but this problem happens rarely.My problem After tapping 100 times to phone.Thanks